# Cold Start Performance WPF

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml

I am using the performance analysis tools within Visual Studio to evaluate a rather large and complex WPF application I am working on. I've been able to get cold start time reduced significantly by lazy loading most of the user controls that previously I just loaded on the application start however I am still seeing the bulk of my CPU cycles spent within the assembly 'PresentationFramework.ni.dll'. This doesn't help me figure out what the root cause is because all it says is that the time is spent on a particular user control's 'InitializeComponent' (i.e. XAML parsing) or Window.Show (i.e. XAML parsing).

My question is this: how can I get more granular insights into what specific XAML elements are causing the performance issue?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and running Windows 8.1. I used to use the old Windows 7 SDK WPF Performance Toolkit that showed a really useful rendering time display that change the color on screen when a particular UIElement was re-drawing but I can't seem to find the same tool that runs on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the user control has a "deep" visual tree,so it spends time initialising. I did face this myself and used a workaround to load the user controls in background as soon as the application starts.hope this helps.

Comment: amol, Thank you for your answer. I up-ticked your answer because you partially answered my question. You are correct, the CPU usage is a result of XAML parsing. The excessive parsing is due to a deep tree but I was hoping to find a better way to finding the worse performing XAML bits without tearing apart my app one user control at a time. I too broke apart the user controls by injecting PRISM regions and waiting until a view's Loaded event fires before registering the view's with the region. This is the PRISM-way of lazy loading user controls like you described was your solution.